# Save all images in UICollectionView as one image

Tags: ios, objective-c, collectionview

I am creating picture masked app for iOS. In my app, I listed all modified pics in collection view as thumbnail(that cells are custom). And I want to save all items(that items are be custom cells in collectionView) in collectionView as 1 image . Is this possible? if it isn't is there a way to save like that?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you show some relevant code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can achieve so by taking a screenshot programmatically. The update in iOS7 made it more efficient. The ways to do it is as following:

```
snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates

resizableSnapshotViewFromRect:afterScreenUpdates:withCapInsets

drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates
```

Then you can convert the returned `UIView` into a image and save it.

Comment: The image quality after the screenshot will be the same if i save it as a PNG?

Comment: It will be the same resolution as the screen is.

Comment: So this is how photo frame apps work? Just some images loaded into various views and printscreen?

Comment: No I would not make such assumption. But for this question this should work.

Comment: Thank you for all answers. @TonyD; is it get screenshot of all screen or can we set border to screenshot rect? I guess this code might be useful "resizableSnapshotViewFromRect:afterScreenUpdates:withCapInsets". I will try...

Comment: Very glad that I can help.